# Using jCrop api to show coordinates of selected crop area

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using JCROP `jquery` plugin for cropping and uploading images.

I want to know how to call `showCoords` function on form `submit` or on a button click.

API only provides documentation for call it `onselect` or `onchange`, but I want to call it `onsubmit` and want to know what parameter I have to pass.

My example url

http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=handler

Comment: what the hell all people who dislike this question. when its clearly informative which is usable for many jquery plugins

Answer (score 3):

To show the coordinates without using an event, you can use the `tellSelect()` method from the [jCrop API](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_API.html)

Basic usage can be like this:

```
var jcrop_api;
function initJcrop(oImg){
    oImg.Jcrop(
        {},function(){
            // initiate api
            jcrop_api = this;
         }
    );
};      

$(function($){
    // initiate jcrop:
    initJcrop($('#cropbox'));
    // add button handler - but this can be any function
    $("#show").click(function () {
        // get the coordinates.
         console.log(jcrop_api.tellSelect());
    });
});
```

[This jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4zYgf/160/) demonstrates the usage of tellSelect